# Iterating functions in a subsetted data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I need to automatize the extraction of several descriptive statistics and functions in a subsetted data frame. Here is a simple example of what I need:
So I have a data frame with two variables. The first one **(x)** is a factor and the second one **(y)** is numeric.

```
x <- c("red", "red", "black", "black","blue","blue") 
y <- c(7,3,4,2,4,3)
data<-data.frame(x,y)

for (i in levels(data$x)){
  assign(paste("Sub",i,sep="."),subset(data,data$x==i))
  }
```

After subsetting the data frame by the x I want to automatize the calculation of the sum, the mean and the sd of the y value of each subsets. I don’t have any clue how I should do it or were I should start. Can anyone help me?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: No help avaliable????? why? is there any problem with the question?